# ¿Como puedo hacer un conteo de usuarios registrados por día?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Quiero hacer una condición que para cuando busque usuarios registrados por día, no me sume los usuarios en total, por ejemplo que si busco del día 2023/11/13 al 2023/11/15, que sume por día y no el total de los días consultados

```
<?php

$start_date = $_POST['start_date'];
$end_date = $_POST['end_date'];`` 

$stm = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuarios_registrados WHERE id_empleado = 
? AND fecha BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date'");                                        
$empleado = $_SESSION['id'];
$stm->execute(array($empleado));
$existente = $stm->fetchColumn();

if($existente > 0){
         echo 'Pide';
} else {
         echo 'Pediste';
?>
```

Comment: Hola. Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Podrías mostrar un ejemplo del resultado que esperas, basado en un pequeño set de datos. Por otra parte, ¿ese código funciona realmente? ¿No estás mezclando `mysqli` con `PDO`?

Comment: Me equivoque al publicar una parte del código,  en cuanto al resultado que quisiera es que, por ejemplo en mi código si busco registros entre los días 2023/11/15 y 2023/11/15 si me salen solo los usuarios que se registraron que por ejemplo serian 2 ese día, pero si quiero filtrar entre mas días, como por ejemplo 2023/11/13 al 2023/11/15  me sale que el  dia15 tiene mas registros, porque lo suma con los días anteriores

Answer (score 0):

Solo tienes que agrupar por fecha

```
SELECT COUNT(*), fecha FROM usuarios_registrados 
WHERE id_empleado = ? AND fecha BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date' 
GROUP BY fecha
```

Comment: No me funciono al ponerlo así, me sigue dando el mismo resultado, pero muchas gracias por tu ayuda